# Changing state of Jcheckbox using if condition

Tags: java

Am new in java, and am trying to make a programme that when a user selects a particular data field from the database the result is displayed in a Jtextfield and then changes the state of the Jcheckbox to true.

Below is a sample of my code.

```
private void check123(){

    String check1 = JTextField.getText();

    if (check1.equals("true")) {
        JCheckBox.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Kindly advice cause i dont know where am going wrong.
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: looks ok... check if this JCheckBox.setSelected(true); is working without the if condition....

Comment: Is the content of the text field really the string "true"? Or do you want to check if it contains any text?

Comment: yes the content in the JTextField  contains a String "true"

Comment: I think problem is not with this part of your code. Most probably in the part which invoke the method check123()

Comment: Does this compile? You are calling `setSelected()` like a static method which makes no sense. You have to apply it to the specific `JCheckBox` instance variable. Same for `JTextField.getText()`.

Comment: yes its  compiling.But when i press Jbutton where i have called method check123() nothing happens

Comment: thanks seen where i was making the mistake.. Thanks all for your feedback